# Setting ColdFusion variables during a HTTP request

Tags: variables, coldfusion, httprequest, coldfusion-10

I'm currently working on the acknowledge receipt response used in SagePay on my website. I've noticed you can do things such as invoke components, read and output variables, but it doesn't allow you to set variables - even if those variables already exist. Is this the case with all HTTP requests or am i simply doing something wrong? My first thought would be if it can execute server side script then surely setting variables (session i must state - not local) should not be an issue.

Comment: is this a 'webhook' call from SagePay back to your server confirming things? If so, it'll work, but likely won't have the session cookie present in the request, so the request won't be associated with the user's session. You may need to add a little detail about the process for us to help more

Comment: Might help to see some of your code to see what type of variables you're having problems setting.

Comment: Saying _"doesn't allow"_ implies an error is occurring, but you haven't shared one. If there is no error then you need to state the unexpected behaviour making you assume setting a variable is not succeeding.

Comment: @barnyr your answer has solved my issues. Sometimes it can be easy to forget that session variables apply to the client only. SagePays call would have set up a session for SagePay - hence why it wasn't creating what i was expecting. Going to set up some new database fields to store relevant information.